# sDNA file error

Tags: sdna

I still failed to run sDNA on my computer. I tried to do the same thing with another computer and it succeeded. I believe there is a problem with my computer. Here is the error message popped up after I used sDNA in ArcGIS Pro.

```
Running external command: "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA_GIS\bin\\sdnaprepare.py" --im "net=C:/Dissertation/GIS-dissertation/GIS-dissertation.gdb/Central_Route" --om "net=C:/Dissertation/GIS-dissertation/GIS-dissertation.gdb/Central_prepare;errors=C:/Dissertation/GIS-dissertation/GIS-dissertation.gdb/Central_prepare" "start_gs=;e
nd_gs=;xytol=0.001;ztol=0.001;action=REPAIR;nearmisses;duplicates;isolated;island=;data_absolute=;data_unitlength=;data_text="

Using XYTolerance of input feature class: 0.001000

Using ZTolerance of input feature class: 0.001000

sDNA sdnaprepare config: start_gs=;end_gs=;xytol=0.001;ztol=0.001;action=REPAIR;nearmisses;duplicates;isolated;island=;data_absolute=;data_unitlength=;data_text=;arcxytol=0.001000;arcztol=0.001000;

Loading DLL C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA_GIS\\x64\\sdna_vs2008.dll

ERR: Traceback (most recent call last):
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA_GIS\bin\\sdnaprepare.py", line 4, in <module>
ERR:     commandline_integral_prepare("sdnaprepare")    
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA_GIS\commandline_integral_prepare.py", line 103, in commandline_integral_prepare
ERR:     dll = options.dll)
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA_GIS\runcalculation.py", line 58, in runcalculation
ERR:     tablecollection1d = TableCollection()
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA_GIS\sdnapy.py", line 229, in __init__
ERR:     self.dll=_dll()
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA_GIS\sdnapy.py", line 44, in _dll
ERR:     __initialize_dll()
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\sDNA_GIS\sdnapy.py", line 84, in __initialize_dll
ERR:     __dll_instance = windll.LoadLibrary(str(__sdna_dll_path))
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 442, in LoadLibrary
ERR:     return self._dlltype(name)
ERR:   File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
ERR:     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
ERR: OSError: [WinError 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool f
or more detail

External command completed
Process did not complete successfully
Failed to execute (sDNAPrepare).
```

[image]

Comment: I know nothing about sDNA, but [googling that error](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+application+has+failed+to+start+because+its+side-by-side+configuration+is+incorrect%22) suggests you need to install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0)

Comment: I have already had that application installed.

Comment: I'm wondering from your other post whether you fixed this? But as you are using sDNA from a 64 bit platform (ArcGIS Pro) I think you would need the 64-bit VS2008 redistributable https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15336