# sDNA Installation - Unable to load DLL 'sdna_vs2008.dll'

Tags: sdna

Failed to install with the following shown on error box of "sDNA License Manager"? What can I do?

See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'sdna_vs2008.dll': The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)
at sdna_unlock.Form1.authorize_sdna_get_challenge(StringBuilder serial, StringBuilder challenge, Int32 maxlength)
at sdna_unlock.Form1.AuthButtonChallenge_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.

Comment: I suspect this is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387191/sdna-file-error - have you tried installing the visual C++ 2008 redistributable, 32 or 64 bit as appropriate? alas you may need to search for a copy as microsoft seem to have taken it offline

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable, then it will work.